# Validar edittext vacío y que cumpla requisitos

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Lo que quiero que haga es que verifique si el editText age esta vacío o sí ha sido rellenado que el numero introducido sea mayor a 18, si alguna de estas es cierta quiero que salga un Toast que indique que hay un error en el editText.
Si de lo contrario son falsas ambas quiero que me salga otro Toast que me diga que 
esta todo correcto.

El código con el que tengo problemas es:

```
    age = findViewById(R.id.age);
    String age1 = age.getText().toString().trim();
    int ageInt = Integer.parseInt(age1);
    if ( age1.isEmpty() || (ageInt < 18)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "te faltan campos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "muy bien!" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Hola Alex, bienvenido a stackoverflow. Respecto a tu pregunta, es recomendable que seas un poco mas específico al detallar el contexto del problema, de tal manera que los miembros de la comunidad puedan entender el origen del problema, el objetivo a alcanzar y el camino a tomar.

Comment: Muchas gracias, efectivamente soy nuevo en esto y no sabia como plantear correctamente mi pregunta. Lo he editado para ver si así queda mas claro.

Comment: Quq error te da? Porque a simple vista parece que todo este bien.

Comment: Gracias por mejorar tu respuesta, en el caso de Android siempre es valioso agregar el mensaje de error desplegado en el LogCat @AlexHernandez. He agregado respuesta, saludos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @Jorgesys tu respuesta me ha resuelto el problema. En cuanto al LogCat no tengo ni idea de como debe ponerse aquí. Cuando tenga algo de tiempo veo bien como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema principal es al tratar de convertir a entero el valor introducido en el `EditText`, esto sucede en esta linea

```
Integer.parseInt(age1);
```

para evitar este problema te sugiero agregar una validacion mediante el siguiente metodo:

```
public static boolean esNumerico(String valor){     
    try{
        if(valor!= null){
            Integer.parseInt(valor);
        }
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
         return false; 
    }
    return false;
}
```

Este metodo retornara `true` si el valor es numerico, en caso contrario `false`.

```
age = findViewById(R.id.age);
String age1 = age.getText().toString().trim();
//int ageInt = Integer.parseInt(age1);

if ( age1.isEmpty() ){
    Toast.makeText(this, "te faltan campos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else if(!esNumerico(age1)){
  Toast.makeText(this, "El valor introducido es incorecto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else if(Integer.parseInt(age1) < 18){
 Toast.makeText(this, "Edad no permitida", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else if(Integer.parseInt(age1) > 18){
     Toast.makeText(this, "muy bien!" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

---

O puedes usar este metodo que realiza las validaciones requeridas

```
public static boolean esValorValido(String valor){
    try{
        if(valor!= null){
            if(!valor.isEmpty()) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(valor) > 18) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

y simplemente llamarlo de esta forma:

```
   age = findViewById(R.id.age);
    String age1 = age.getText().toString().trim();
    //int ageInt = Integer.parseInt(age1);
    if ( esValorValido(age1) ){
        Toast.makeText(this, "te faltan campos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "muy bien!" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer.parseInt(age1)
```

Comprueba que al hacer este cast, el valor de age1 no sea nulo.

```
if(!age1.isEmpty()){
    //Do the cast to int
}
```